# Generating random float between negative and positive opengl es java

Tags: java, android, random, opengl-es

Im studying opengles. I want to know how can i generate between -1 to 1. Thats because opengl normalized device coordinates is only between -1 and 1. Some mentioned that random float is only between 0.0 and 0.9999999.

here is my code

```
 points.addParticles(new GeoPoint(-random.nextFloat(),random.nextFloat(),random.nextFloat()),180);
```

Thats for x,y,z and random color.

[image]

I just want to generate random points inside the screen with random location.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well [`Random.nextFloat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextFloat%28%29) gives a value greater than or equal to 0, and less than 1 - i.e. a range of [0, 1). So to map that to a range of `[-1, 1)` you just need to multiply by 2 and subtract 1.

```
float value = random.nextFloat() * 2 - 1;
```

In general, to get a value in the range `[x, y)` you would use

```
random.nextFloat() * (x - y) + x
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you.. Have to wait 9 mins to accept your answer :D

Comment: If we want between [-1, 1) in the form of [x,y) then  x = -1 and y = 1                      and (x - y) = ( (-1) - (1) ) = -2. Is here a typo or I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Well you could use one more random, which would decide if you multiply by 1 or (-1)?
if random >0.5 (first_random *1) else (first_random*(-1))

Comment: this answer is better because you only get even numbers the other way.